# How to create a Pivot Table in Excel with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

Can someone tell me? How to create a pivot table in MS Excel using Javascript API? (Web Addins) I know how to create it with VSTO, VBA. But, I don't know how to create it with Javascript API. Is it real? How can I use add-ins if I can not even create a pivot table? Thanks

Comment: Hi @grishin I designed initial pivot table API spec a couple of weeks ago. I am trying to persuade the team sharing the spec directly to the community to allow people comment directly. This can help us move faster too. I will share the spec if I can get permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the [PivotTable](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/pivottable) object only supports a `refresh()` method. There is a [UserVoice request to support creating PivotTables](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/7904691-add-abitility-to-create-pivot-table-via-office-jav) that is currently listed as "In Backlog" but there isn't an ETA for what it might roll out.

Comment: Does this mean that i must return to the VSTO? I just decided everything was simple, but no! New technologies.

Comment: Basic APIs to create and update Pivot Table are under development. There is no timeline for release - but should be available for beta trial end of this quarter or around. Are there specific features you are looking for?